# Getting if Screen ON/OFF and if Application is in Background/Foreground

Tags: android, background, screen

I decided to post two question in one post, because it's quite same problem.

I need to know when screen is ON or OFF so i can turn LED. The second one I need to know if my applicaiton is in backgorund or it is in foreground, to manage sending notification on some actiong when app is in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been similar questions on Stackoverflow earlier. Here are links to a few of them:

1. [How to determine if one of my activities is in the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314969/how-to-determine-if-one-of-my-activities-is-in-the-foreground)
2. [android:how to check if application is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183932/androidhow-to-check-if-application-is-running-in-background)
3. [How can I tell if Android app is running in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504632/how-can-i-tell-if-android-app-is-running-in-the-foreground)

Answer (score 13):

Adding answer for screen ON/OFF check:

```
// If you use API20 or more:
DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
for (Display display : dm.getDisplays()) {
    if (display.getState() != Display.STATE_OFF) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;

// If you use less than API20:
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
if (powerManager.isScreenOn()){ return true; }
```

Note that `Display.getState()` can also return `STATE_DOZE` and `STATE_DOZE_SUSPEND` which means that the screen is on in an special way. More info on `Display.getState()` and his return values here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getState()

Also note that although official documentation recommends using `isInteractive()` instead of `isScreenOn()`, if you really want to know the status of the screen, `Display.getState()` is a better option because of the 'special' conditions that sets the screen on while the device is not interactive.

Comment: the official documentation says `Note in particular that the device is still considered to be interactive while dreaming`. I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/28747907/1115059 to be more accurate and updated

Comment: @Jaydeep Hmmm, interesting. Going to update the answer. Thank you!

Comment: how to use getState() method in the background suppose when display goes off need to to some work in background .(ACTION_SCREEN_OFF deal with is user interactive or not but not with display on/off). any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can know if you're in the foreground or not through use of your activity's onWindowFocusChanged() callback; see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html

You can also create a broadcast receiver to capture SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF events. [Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) is an example.