# Weird behavior of activity (life cycle) when called on SCREEN_OFF intent fired

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing slideshow functionality, this stop and restart creates issue in slideshow flow, can we change it ?

Log of life cycle method

```
07-04 22:47:27.944: D/ReceiverActivity(7365): Activity Life cycle - onStart called
07-04 22:47:27.944: D/ReceiverActivity(7365): Activity Life cycle - onResume called
07-04 22:47:28.467: D/ReceiverActivity(7365): Activity Life cycle - onStop called
07-04 22:47:29.139: D/ReceiverActivity(7365): Activity Life cycle - onRestart called
07-04 22:47:29.139: D/ReceiverActivity(7365): Activity Life cycle - onStart called
07-04 22:47:29.139: D/ReceiverActivity(7365): Activity Life cycle - onResume called
```

Here is my app code snippets

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Intent ri = new Intent(context, ReceiverActivity.class);
            ri.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(ri);
    }
}


public class ReceiverActivity extends Activity
{
    StringBuilder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        // Turn on the screen unless we are being launched from the AlarmAlert
        // subclass as a result of the screen turning off.
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.launcher_layout);
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("onCreate called.");
        Log.e("ReceiverActivity", "String : " + builder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d("ReceiverActivity","Activity Life cycle - onStart called");
        super.onStart();
        builder.append("\nonStart called.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d("ReceiverActivity","Activity Life cycle - onResume called");
        super.onResume();
        builder.append("\nonResume called.");
        Log.e("ReceiverActivity", "String : " + builder.toString());
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(builder.toString());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.d("ReceiverActivity","Activity Life cycle - onRestart called");
        super.onRestart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d("ReceiverActivity","Activity Life cycle - onStop called");
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What 's your question?

Comment: Is the issue that during screen blank the Activity seems to get taken through the onPause onResume cycle a lot when you would expect it not to?

Comment: @NeilTownsend, nope, but it's get stopped and restarted immediately, why this happening?

Comment: I don't know, but it definitely happens, I have seen similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that you need to know if the screen is actually on or off when onResume is being called, to determine how you should handle the event. You want to check:

- That your activity is in the foreground.
- That the screen is on.

[Getting if Screen ON/OFF and if Application is in Background/Foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305563/getting-if-screen-on-off-and-if-application-is-in-background-foreground) gives clear answers to how to do both of these.