# Disabling onPause() when screen is off

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any way to disable **onPause()** when screen is off and disable **onResume()** when screen is on?

Comment: what does "disable" mean?

Comment: Do you want to stop executing code in `onPause` methods when screen off ? If so check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960924/how-to-detect-whether-screen-is-on-or-off-if-api-level-is-4

Comment: I you mean onPause / onResume  not being called ... well its part of  how android apps work.  No you can't avoid the Activity lifecycle to run properly. Instead you should learn how to handle it.

Comment: I do not want the activity to be set in onPause statu when screen is off

Comment: to prvent to go screen off you can use weak lock and in xml file you can set android:keepScreenOn="true" and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html