# Detect Device Wakeness In Android

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I'm trying to create a service that run in background in android.. That service should work only when the device is on sleep *(Means that screen is off)*..

I think that can be done using a service but I don't know how to detect if the phone is awake or not.. Any Idea ? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For screen on-off state, you can try with `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` intents, as shown in this blog post:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

From here  : [How to detect whether screen is on or off if API level is 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960924/how-to-detect-whether-screen-is-on-or-off-if-api-level-is-4)