# How to create a countdown timer that stops and "waits" when the screen is off, resumes when back on. Android

Tags: android, android-studio, timer, screen, countdown

How to create a countdown timer that stops and "waits" when the screen is off, resumes when back on.

Just like the title says, how to program a basic countdown timer in Android Studio that stops when the user closes the phone, (screen is off), and restarts when the screen turns back on. Still a complete noob at this and I would just need basic code that works and does this.

Thanks

I already have a basic interface...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler with a Runnable, which is called every second.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int countdown = 300; // set countdown value in seconds
Runnable countdownRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        countdown--;

        if(countdown == 0) {
            // countdown finished
        } else {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

First, start the countdown with `handler.post(countdownRunnable)`. In the Activity/Fragment `onStop()`, remove the runnable from the handler with `handler.removeCallbacks(countdownRunnable);`, and add it again in `onStart()` with `handler.post(countdownRunnable)`.

Also, don’t forget to save and restore the state (current countdown value).

Answer (score 0):

As Nacho L. Answered On [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960924/how-to-detect-whether-screen-is-on-or-off-if-api-level-is-4)
For screen on-off state, you can try with ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF Intents, as shown in this blog post: [http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/[2](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/)

Comment: Thank you! Will review this when I have time